# Get last unique row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a table looking like this:

```
    id1    |    id2    |    dateUpdate
==========================================
    aaa    |    111    |    2016-01-01
    aaa    |    111    |    2016-01-02
    aaa    |    222    |    2016-01-05
    aaa    |    222    |    2016-01-15
    bbb    |    333    |    2016-01-05
    bbb    |    444    |    2016-01-01
    ccc    |    111    |    2016-01-02
```

I'd like to get only the latest row for each id1/id2 couple:

```
    id1    |    id2    |    dateUpdate
==========================================
    aaa    |    111    |    2016-01-02
    aaa    |    222    |    2016-01-15
    bbb    |    333    |    2016-01-05
    bbb    |    444    |    2016-01-01
    ccc    |    111    |    2016-01-02
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look into using [pivot tables](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot07.html).  They have a grouping functionality similar to what you would use in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screen shot showing function]Use Aggregate Function

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, 1/($A$2:$A$99=E2)*($B$2:$B$99=F2)*($C$2:$C$99), 1)
```

You have to put the unique combinations in column E2 and Column F2 downwards 
You have five unique combinations

```
COLUMN A      COLUMN B 

aaa           111
aaa           222
bbb           333
bbb           444
ccc           111
```

And Aggregate Funtion is to be put in column G2 and fill down downwards.

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, 1/($A$2:$A$99=E2)*($B$2:$B$99=F2)*($C$2:$C$99), 1)
```

Regarding Syntax 14 is for Large value that is the for example larger for first aaa  111 combination that is #02-01-2016#
Next digit 6 in formula is for ignoring errors
You can quickly get the pseudo-Last value  using the [AGGREGATE function.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF).
This is a standard non-array formula that does NOT require Ctrl+Shift+Enter. AGGREGATE was introduced with Excel 2010.

`($A$2:$A$99=E2)` checks which value of column A matches with the first unique value of column A of unique combination of A  & B
This is converted to an array of logical values which gives an array of True Or False. Dividing 1 by these logical values give either 1 or DIV# error. Similar process is adopted for Column B values mentioned in column F. I have taken data limited to 99 rows. If it more number of rows you change the figure of 99 to a higher figure as per your requirements.
HTH

**EDIT**
You can also go for pivot table solution as suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen in his comments. Snapshot given here-under illustrates that approach.

[image: pivot table approach]

`id1` and `id2` are taken as filter fields and Maximum Value of `dateUpdate` is chosen in the value field.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be on the right way to me. How do you get the E and F columns?

Comment: We have to put unique combinations in column E and F. I will fully explain the formula in my edit. This function is available for Excel 2010 onwards.

Comment: You can also go for pivot table solution as suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen in his comments. Snapshot given here-under illustrates that approach.

Comment: Nice in depth explanation of the aggregate function.

Comment: @Forward Ed I am getting lot of inspiration from your posts and propel me to slowly and steadily  move forward. Thanks.